# Страница перезагружается при отправке формы ajax

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ajax

Есть такая форма:

```html
<form id="visa-form" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/template-parts/mail.php'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>ФИО</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_fullname" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Пол</label>
            <select name="user_gender" class="form-control">
                <option value="Мужской">Мужской</option>
                <option value="Женский">Женский</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Номер телефона</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_phone" class="form-control" pattern="\d*" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Эл. почта</label>
            <input type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Место работы</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_workplace" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Загрузить фото</label>
            <input type="file" name="photo_scan" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Загрузить скан паспорта</label>
            <input type="file" name="passport_scan" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" align="center">
            <input id="send-visa-form" type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить заявку" class="btn btn-info" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

и такой js:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function sendAjaxForm(ajax_form, url) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: jQuery("#" + ajax_form).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    $("#visa-form-btn").click(function() {
        sendAjaxForm('visa-mail', "../template-parts/mail.php/");
        return false;
    });
});
```

После нажатия на кнопку отправки формы должно было выводится окно `alert()` с соответствующим сообщением, но вместо этого страница попросту перезагружается. Я пробовал убирать тег `action` у форм, в таком случае форма вообще не отправляется, а страница просто перезагружается. Не могу понять в чем дело


*P.S. Есть подозрения указание путей, хотя полученный файл возвращает статус 200

P.S. Не думаю что содержимое скрипта `mail.php` для отправки письма нужно, `php` работает*

Comment: добавьте в функцию обработки клика event.preventDefault(): `$("#visa-form-btn").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); sendAjaxForm('visa-mail', "../template-parts/mail.php/");
        return false;
    });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function sendAjaxForm(ajax_form, url) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: jQuery("#" + ajax_form).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    $("#visa-form-btn").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        sendAjaxForm('visa-mail', "../template-parts/mail.php/");
        return false;
    });
});
```

**UPD:** А еще лучше - перехватывайте не клик по кнопке, а сам сабмит формы:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function sendAjaxForm(ajax_form, url) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: jQuery("#" + ajax_form).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    $("#visa-form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        sendAjaxForm('visa-mail', "../template-parts/mail.php/");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: не-а, `event.preventDefault()` не сработал

Comment: так у вас кнопка sumbit имеет id="send-visa-form", а prevent default вы указываете для #visa-form-btn. Вот ваша форма и отрабатывает свое стандартное поведение с перезагрузкой страницы

Comment: @МаксМаксимус, мы отменяем то событие, которое случается. Если нужно отменить клик по кнопке - отменяем клик по ктопке. А если нужно отменить сабмит формы - отменяем сабмит формы.

Comment: Я немного исправлял ответ, обновите страницу и убедитесь что я не исправил то о чем вы говорили

Comment: $("#visa-form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        sendAjaxForm('visa-mail', "../template-parts/mail.php/");
        return false;
    });

Comment: если не будет срабатывать, значит открывайте консоль и смотрите какие там показаны ошибки

Comment: выполнение ajax запрос работает, теперь не работает сам запрос. Т.е. выполняется `error`